# Node Js url.format() not working properly inside Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, url

I'm having problem loading a local pdf file using url.format(). Here is my code:

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/file.pdf'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
}));
```

But getting two times `c:\` inside the formatted url. This is the error i'm getting

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\C:\Projects\Experiments\Electron\angular-electron\dist\assets\file.pdf'
```

Comment: Can you provide more context?   Is this code Angular code that runs in a client browser, or NodeJS code that runs on a server?  It looks like NodeJS server-side code to me.  When / how is this code run?  Is the error a NodeJS console error or a browser console error?

Comment: @JeffryHouser This is client side code and runs inside the browser to display the pdf. Also i'm getting the error inside the console of browser

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would want a browser to access the local file system to open a PDF, but what is the `win` variable?  What is the `loadURL()` method?  What is `__dirname` variable and where is it defined?  None of this looks like Angular code to me, are you sure you correctly tagged the question?